# C3js timeseries flow

Tags: d3.js, charts, time-series, c3.js

Based on the available examples I am trying to create a line chart with multiple lines that flows timeseries on update.

Creating the chart:

```
// The number of columns is variable
var columns = [];
columns.push(['time', time]);
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  // The number of columns is variable
  columns.push([values[i].name, pairValue(values[i])]);
}

var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: selection,
  data: {
    x: 'time',
      columns: columns
    },
    axis: {
      x: {
        type: 'timeseries',
        tick: {
          format: '%X'
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Updating the chart:

```
// The number of columns is variable
var columns = [];
columns.push(['time', time]);
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  // pairValue extracts value from object
  columns.push([values[i].name, pairValue(values[i])]);
}

// I have saved the chart object on creation
var chart = __charts[tag(selection)]; 
chart.flow({
  columns: columns,
  to: time,
  duration: 1000
});
```

Though creation works fine, the update does not move the X tick and the updates happen outside the viewable area. Any suggestions are very welcome.